# iOS PDFView causes underlying assertion when autoScales is set to true

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, ios-pdfkit

Im working on an application that needs to display a pretty large PDF file. I'm using PDFKits PDFView for this, which is then wrapped in a UIViewRepresentable. The problem is that when setting `PDFView.autoScales = true` i get an error on startup. The application still works and so does the autoScales feature but I would still like to fix the error. I should also mention that I'm a complete beginner when it comes to iOS development.

This is my implementation of makeUIView:

```
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    pdfView.autoScales = true
    pdfView.pageBreakMargins.top = 0.0
    pdfView.pageBreakMargins.bottom = 0.0
    pdfView.pageShadowsEnabled = false
    pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)        
    return pdfView
}
```

And this is the error:

```
[Assert] -[UIScrollView _clampedZoomScale:allowRubberbanding:]: Must be called with non-zero scale
[Unknown process name] CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
```

They seem to get printed whenever the PDFView gets initialized. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: If it does not affect app functionality then ignore it - it is UIKit internals.

Comment: I agree, ignoring it is probably not a problem. Messages appearing in the console from system internals are not uncommon.  But try setting autoScales to true _after_ the document and margins have been set.

Comment: @CenkBilgen Unfortunately didn't help, but okay, I will ignore it for now, thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue right now. Everything seems to be working but I'm wondering if anyone figured out why we're getting these error messages. I've tried some of the suggestions here and other things but the nothing seems to make these go away. @HermanHanssonSöderlund have you had any issues/crashes since you originally encountered this?

Answer (score 6):

I have meet the same issue, and I have fixed now.

Your pdfView should set the frame first.You can give any value.

```swift
let pdfView = PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))   
self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
```

It is OK now, and then solve the error

Comment: Didn't get rid of the error for me. Is this for SwiftUI? Like the others, I'll ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just ignoring it. Seems to work fine.